# Como alterar o valor de um jLabel com um jButton (Netbeans)

Tags: java, jbutton, jlabel

Sou iniciante no Java, e estou querendo criar um programa supostamente bem simples. Dentro de um panel só existe um jlabel e um jbutton. O jLabel está com o valor "0". Ao Clicar no jbutton, a ideia é que ele aumente um número a cada clique no jButton.

Answer (score 0):

`botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    jlabel.setText(Integer.parseInt(jlabel.getText()) + 1); 
  } 
} );`

Nao sei ao certo se esta função esta correta, pois nao abri a IDE para tester.

Entretanto, não e difícil fazer o que deseja, passe a função para ele executar quando aperta algum botão igual no exemplo acima. dentro da função e so dar um setText naquele jlabel seu, passando o texto do mesmo nao esquecendo de converter para inteiro e incrementando 1. pronto :)

Comment: Não consegui ainda. Na real eu sei que o conceito é bem simples, mas a prática está sendo bem complicada. Eu já consegui fazer uma lista com AbstractTabelModel e campos para cadastro, tudo completo, mas alterar um elemento através de um botão ta sendo bem difícil

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Deixo aqui pra quem precise também:

```
private int senha = 0;

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(senha == 50){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Limite de Senhas já entregue.");
        } else{
            senha++;
            this.jLabel1.setText(senha+"");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Marque sua resposta depois [(veja como)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) pra não deixar a pergunta em aberto, ok?